# Group multiple elements in array with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-reduce

I have an array

```
[
  { price: 10 },
  { price: 10 },
  { price: 10 },
  { price: 10 },
  { price: 20 },
  { price: 20 },
]
```

and I want it transformed into

```
[
  { numElements: 4, price: 10 },
  { numElements: 2, price: 20 },
]
```

I have tried using `arr.reduce((prev, curr) => ..., [])` to accomplish this, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Can you show the attempt with reduce? Using that is a very good start (not being condescending).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to group an array of objects by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774697/how-to-group-an-array-of-objects-by-key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A traditional method might use a `for/loop` to wrangle the data, but these days JavaScript has a number of functional methods that can help. This code uses `reduce` and `map`. To get your data in the format you want is a two stage process.

First, use `reduce` to create a hash table using the price as a key (because you know the each price is going to be unique:

```
const obj = arr.reduce((p, c) => {

  // If price exists as a key its value by 1
  // otherwise set it to 1.
  p[c.price] = ++p[c.price] || 1;
  return p;
}, {});
```

OUTPUT

```
{
  "10": 4,
  "20": 2
}
```

As it stands you've got a perfectly good object that you can access by the key/price and I would probably just stop there:

```
obj['10'] // 4
```

But if you want to get that data into the format in your question, `map` over the object keys to return an array of new objects.

```
const out = Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
  return { price: +key, numElements: obj[key] };
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/6x6rw6fr/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
var hash = {}, result = [];

 arr.forEach(function(el){
   if(hash[el.price]){
     hash[el.price].numElements++;
   }else{
     result.push(hash[el.price]={price:el.price,numElements:1});
  }
});
```

[Run](http://jsbin.com/jofubivaye/edit?console)

May use a hash table for price lookup. Or with reduce and find:

```
 arr.reduce((res,{price})=>
  (( res.find(el=>el.price===price) || res[res.push({price,numElements:0})-1] )
  .numElements++,res)
);
```

[Run](http://jsbin.com/qedomuxuma/edit?console)

Answer (score 0):

You can use try this:

```
let arr = [
  { price: 10 },
  { price: 10 },
  { price: 10 },
  { price: 10 },
  { price: 20 },
  { price: 20 },
]

let result = []

let counter = {}

arr.forEach( el => {

  if (!counter[el.price]) counter[el.price] = 1
  else counter[el.price]++

  console.log(counter[el.price])

})

for (let id in counter) {
  result.push({numElements: counter[id], price: id})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the data comes sorted on `price` property, with a single `.reduce()` you may do as follows;

```js
var data   = [{ price: 10 }, { price: 10 }, { price: 10 }, { price: 10 }, { price: 20 }, { price: 20 }],
    result = data.reduce((r,d,i) => i ? r[r.length-1].price === d.price ? (r[r.length-1].numElemenets++, r)
                                                                        : (r.push(Object.assign({}, d, {numElemenets: 1})),r)
                                      : [Object.assign({}, d, {numElemenets: 1})], {});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could look up the price in the result array and if not found insert a new object.

```js
var data = [{ price: 10 }, { price: 10 }, { price: 10 }, { price: 10 }, { price: 20 }, { price: 20 }],
    grouped = data.reduce((r, { price }) => {
        var t = r.find(p => price === p.price);
        t || r.push(t = { numElements: 0, price });
        t.numElements++;
        return r;
    }, []);
    
console.log(grouped);
```